# Converting a column with the format integer64 to character in R

Tags: r, integer

I wanted to ask you guys if you know any way to convert a column which is in the integer64 format to character in R.
I downloaded this dataframe and in there one column (the one I need) is in integer64. Tbh I dont really know what that is, but I need it to be a character in order to use it further. I was planing to do a left join with another dataframe but because this one is in character I cant.

Here an example:

```
Dataframe 1 

ID        weight
77560        28
77564         7
77568         5


Dataframe 2

ID        name
77560     Monkey
77564     Rabbit
77569     Chicken
```

So my end goal is to give the ID's in the 1. dataframe the name of the second.

I looked into CRAN and the integer64 and found out that it is in the bit64 package.
I tried several codes such as
`as.character(dataframe2$ID)`
or
`d2 = dataframe2 %>% mutate_at(c("ID"),as.character))`
I think I have to work with the bit64 package since integer64 is "made" with this package, but I could not figure out how.
I also tried the reverse approach to make my ID in the first dataframe into interger64, but I only got NA's, and for further analysis its better to have dataframe2$ID as character.
Adding to that, I was thinking about exporting the dataframe into Excel or googlesheets, but googlesheets didnt know how to handle the integer64 aswell.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?  R does not overwrite objects unless you explicitly re-define them with `<-`.

```r
library(dplyr)

dataframe2 <- 
  dataframe2 %>% 
    mutate(ID = as.character(ID))
```

Comment: Oh, the answer was this simple....
Thank you!

Comment: or `mutate(across(ID, as.character))`

Comment: @BenBolker, how does `across` add anything to a single-column update? *Edit*, I see, perhaps because OP originally tried `mutate_at`, got it.

Comment: it's just a little more compact/reduces repetition. It would be more obviously useful if the column name was something like `IndividualIdentificationNumber`

Comment: @Miga, if this solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it